# SSIS, load file into table with '' (nothing) to get NULL

Tags: t-sql, ssis

I have file with 150 columns and most of them are nothing, represented like 2 consecutive delimiters (`100,,,,,,200`) in this case comma is delimiter so Column0=100, Column1='', Column2='', etc...

What is the fastest (afraid to say mass) way to put this into target table, (and target table has custom DDL can not change, and I have to put in correct way have NULL for date, not 1900-1-1). 
I have series of this files, I can go with SSIS and put  `isNothing ? NULL : Column1` for each of 150 columns,  but maybe there is better way?
I tried to load this file into NEW table and got intermediate table with same Nothing, so now I can compose sql with CASE'ing too.

THanks for you help and sharing your knowledge.
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to check the "Retain null value" box in the flat file source ?

[image]

Hope this Help,